# Symfony Entity Not Saving to the Database on Persist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, orocrm

This works on controllers, however, it doesn't work when injected to a command.

```
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    try {
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setSubject("Test subject");
        $task->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e; //no error
    }
    //prints successful here
}

/**
 * @param string $entityName
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository
 */
protected function getRepository($entityName)
{
    return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($entityName);
}

protected function getDoctrine()
{
    return $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
}
```

The cron is successfully picking it up until the end but it doesn't throw any error or save the entity.

Comment: How is the configuration of the entity done?

Comment: Did you checked the logs ? Does it says that the entities are indeed persisted ?

Comment: Commands are not controllers.  There is no getDoctrine method.  Run the command from outside of the cron to see the error message.  Then look at the docs to see how to get the doctrine entity manager from the container.

Comment: I see you updated the question to show the getDoctrine method.  Does it work now?  Have you tried it from outside of the cron?

Comment: Hey @Cerad. Yes, that works without any error. Except that it doesn't save the said entity. Digging further.

Comment: side note, there is no use in catching an exception and immediately throwing it again, that's the same as not catching it at all

Comment: Anyone guide me, My Magento Version 1.9.2.3, i have installed Bitnami OroCRM in Windows. After successfully installed then i going to Sync. The Sync is not complete i am getting an error like, Jobs Failed  1) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  2)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  3)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  4) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  5) orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1 all the Jobs Failed. My status error : https://justpaste.it/4rkcs  and log error : https://justpaste.it/61uta How can i solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

check the DB, it can be saved but if 'status_id' is empty it will not be shown anywhere